# How to insert row with SQLAlchemy ORM using a subquery with string_agg?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have an SQL query that inserts a row into a table. One of the columns is assigned a value returned from sub-query that aggregates multiple values using `string_agg`. How can this be written using SQLAlchemy ORM?

**The postgres query**

```
INSERT INTO blobs (_id, data) VALUES (nextval('blobs_id_seq'),
  (SELECT string_agg(blobs.data, NULL ORDER BY blobs._id DESC) 
    FROM blobs where blobs._id IN (1,2) ) );
```

**The table ORM**

```py
    class Blob(Base):
      __tablename__ = 'blobs'
      _id = Column(Integer, Sequence('blobs_id_seq'), primary_key=True, unique=True)
     data = Column(LargeBinary)

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    db = Session(engine)
    db.add(Blob(data=b'aa'))
    db.add(Blob(data=b'bb'))
    db.add(Blob(data=b'cc'))
    db.commit()
```

**Invalid ORM insert**

```py
    # Should yield a "Blob" with data = b"bbaa"
    db.add(Blob(data=db.query(func.string_agg(Blob.data, None))
      .filter( Blob._id.in_([1, 2]) )
      .order_by( Blob._id.desc() ) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a dialect specific helper `aggregate_order_by` that renders a query that outputs the expected results.

```py
db.add(Blob(data=db.query(func.string_agg(Blob.data,
    aggregate_order_by(None, Blob._id.desc())))
  .filter( Blob._id.in_([1, 2]) )))
```